# VB Excel Using a column in a table as an array

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am quite new to VB scripting so I am probably missing something quite simple.

I have an excel spreadsheet where there are two tables on two different sheets, and am trying to join the results as text to feed back into a different table.

I am using the following sample VB which results in a Subscript out of range error.

```
Sub ColCars_with_table()

Dim myTableCars As ListObject
Dim myTableColours As ListObject
Dim carAlias As Variant
Dim colourAlias As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

Set myTableCars = Sheets("Cars").ListObjects("CarTable")
Set myTableColours = Sheets("Colours").ListObjects("ColourTable")

carAlias = myTableCars.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
colourAlias = myTableColours.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange

For x = LBound(carAlias) To UBound(carAlias)
    For y = LBound(colourAlias) To UBound(colourAlias)
        MsgBox ("Colour and make is " & colourAlias(y) & " " & carAlias(x))
    Next y
Next x
```

If I convert the VB to have straight arrays I can get it to work:

```
Sub ColCars_without_table()
'this works
carAlias = Array("Subaru", "Toyata", "Ferrari", "Volkswagen", "Audi", "BMW", "Fiat", "Mazda")
colourAlias = Array("Red", "Blue", "Yellow")

For x = LBound(carAlias) To UBound(carAlias)
    For y = LBound(colourAlias) To UBound(colourAlias)
        MsgBox ("This is a " & colourAlias(y) & carAlias(x)) 'this will produce the correct results
    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

I am probably doing something fundamentally wrong with the way I am getting the data out of the tables and hope someone might be able to steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a `named range` to define the Colors and Cars, then populating a variant array in VBA via the named range.

The first step using this approach would be to navigate to `Formulas -> Name Manager` in the Ribbon and [create two named ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx), one for your cars and one for your colors.

Once the named ranges are defined, you can reference them in code like below

```
Sub ColCars_without_table()

Dim carArray() As Variant
Dim colorArray() As Variant

carArray = Range("Cars")        'Populates variant array with values from Cars Named Range
colorArray = Range("Colors")    'Populates variant array with values from Colors Named Range

For x = LBound(carArray, 1) To UBound(carArray, 1)
    For y = LBound(colorArray, 1) To UBound(colorArray, 1)
        MsgBox ("This is a " & colorArray(y, 1) & carArray(x, 1))
    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I was worried that if I created a range in the table that it would not update the range as new entries were added  but it does!

Comment: It is absolutely not necessary to use named ranges (one advantage of the ListObject table is that its DataBodyRange is essentially a dynamic range already!), and you gave no explanation for the part of your answer that actually makes it work without error (properly indexing the 2-dimensional arrays).

Comment: @nanoteknz you're very welcome, best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

> I am probably doing something fundamentally wrong with the way I am getting the data out of the tables

No, but I think you are doing something wrong with how you are iterating your range-arrays. A range array is **always** two-dimensional, even if it is a range of a single column or single row.  In the case of a single column, do this:

```
carAlias = Application.Transpose(myTableCars.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)
```

If the range is a *row*, then you have to double-transpose it, i.e.,:

```
Dim headerRow as Variant
headerRow = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(myTableCars.HeaderRowRange))
```

Then you will end up with a one-dimensional array that does not raise the SOOR error.

The SOOR error in this case raises because you've asked for an element in the array without specifying both dimensions.

Comment: I will look into this solution as well. Thank you for the explanations as well. I think I tried to use the Transpose at one point, although I was probably not utilising it correctly!

Comment: Oh and it was more than likely the dimensions that caused the error. I guess at the time I was looking at both the solutions I had, one worked and the other didn't and didn't bother to look at that aspect! Thank you again